# Cannot change Bundle ID after uploading project do App Store Connect

Tags: xcode, bundle-identifier, app-store-connect

I have a problem with uploading app to the App Store. My story is: a friend of mine has created a project in Xcode and uploaded it to his App Store account. After that, he has sent it to me so I can use it. I've made many modifications on it, changed a bundle ID from his to mine, switched to my provisioning profile, prepared archive and tried to upload. After a while I have received response from the App Store's server that I cannot upload my application, because I don't have permissions to upload an app with XXX App ID. As supposed, XXX was my friend's App ID. Is there any way so un-associate this project with the old App ID?

Comment: It sounds like that you are missing to change the bundle id in the project.

Comment: As I've written, it's been already changed